# Need to charge after 14 days using stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

When I enter my credit it will be billed for $6.95. This is for shipping and handling. The shipping and handling charge gets billed once the card credentials have been entered.

I need to know 14 days later the card will get billed $39.99 for the product.
I need to get an email telling me the card needs to be billed.
Will the credit card automatically be billed in 14 days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is more than one way to skin this cat.

I would approach this problem in Stripe with the following process:

1. create a customer object and charge the customer immediately for the $6.95. https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later
2. subscribe the customer to a plan that has a 14 day free trial period. https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions
3. Listen with a webhook event handler to cancel the subscription after the first $39.99 charge has been processed. https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks The webhook event you would want to respond to after the $39.99 payment is processed would be invoice.payment_succeeded. https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types

This solution would be completely transparent to the user, and completely automated for you. You can use webhooks to automatically send out payment receipts (or any other type of communication), clean up data, or anything else you can imagine. It's a very powerful feature.

Comment: I know this is a very old answer. But can this be solved using Payments API now? https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment